# Are RFCOMM packets guarnteed to be whole?

Tags: linux, bluetooth, bluez, rfcomm, spp

I'm writing an application that interfaces with Bluetooth devices using [Headset Profile](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/profiles-overview). These devices primarily communicate via `AT` commands send over a Serial Port Profile (`SPP`) connection. `SPP` is directly on top of `RFCOMM`.

My concern is whether or not I am guaranteed to receive "whole" packets (`AT` commands), or if there is a possibility that I will need to be able to handle an `AT` command split across multiple packets.

Furthermore, if the `RFCOMM` protocol does not guarantee this, does the protocol stack do any processing to guarantee receiving "whole" `AT` commands? I am using `BlueZ 5.46` on a `Linux 4.12` kernel.

If possible, please reference the standard or an external source that details how `RFCOMM` guarantees this so I can learn a bit more about it.